# A Very weird bug when trying to print the hexadecimal Blake2 hash of a file

Tags: c++, hash, libsodium

I'm writing a tiny program to compute the hash (blake2b) of a file using libsodium and find myself staring at a weird bug.

There's a missing zero in my hexadecimal output which isn't caused by the hash procedure since we're using the same 256 bit truncated hash functions.

Both use Blake2b (optimized for x64).

I made sure to verify that the file was read in total, even if it was the case the output with be totally different since it's a hash function (1 bit is sufficient to have different outputs).

I also used C-style printing and C++ streams to see if it had something to do with format specifiers which showed it wasn't the case.

My program outputs the following :

```
479b5e6da5eb90a19ae1777c8ccc614b5c8f695c9cffbfe78d38b89e40b865
```

When using b2sum command line tool

```
b2sum /bin/ls -l 256
479b5e6da5eb90a19ae1777c8ccc614b**0**5c8f695c9cffbfe78d38b89**0**e40b865
```

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<sstream>
#include<ios>
#include<vector>

#include<sodium.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    using buffer = vector<char>;

    ifstream input(argv[1],ios::binary | ios::ate); 
    // get file size 
    streamsize filesize = input.tellg();
    input.seekg(0,ios::beg);
    // make a buffer with that filesize
    buffer buf(filesize);
    // read the file
    input.read(buf.data(),buf.size());
    input.close();
    // show filesize 
    cout << "Filesize : " << filesize << endl;
    // using the snipped from libsodium docs 
    // https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/hashing/generic_hashing
    // Example 1
    unsigned char hash[crypto_generichash_BYTES];

    crypto_generichash(hash,sizeof(hash),(unsigned char*)buf.data(),buf.size(),NULL,0);

    // Print the hash in hexadecimal
    for(int i = 0; i < crypto_generichash_BYTES; i++)
    {
        printf("%x",hash[i]);
    }
    cout << endl;
    // load the hash into a stringstream using hexadecimal
    stringstream ss;
    for(int i=0; i<crypto_generichash_BYTES;++i)
        ss << std::hex << (int)hash[i];
    std::string mystr = ss.str();  
    // output the stringstream
    cout << mystr << endl;
    cout << "hash length :" << mystr.length() << endl;


}
```

Comment: Hint: what does `printf("%x", 2)` produce? How do you make it outout a fixed width result with leading zeros? How do you do the same with iostreams?

Comment: You really should use your debugger's facilities to view the bytes in memory instead of (possibly) making mistakes in displaying output using streams or `printf`.

Comment: I removed the c tag.I don't get your hint but how does a zero disappear from the middle I just wrote a Go implementation and it's output is similar to b2sum cli tool .

Comment: @halius read the documentation for `printf()` and its `%x` format specifier, that should lead you to understand why some of your zeros are disappearing. You are not telling `printf()` to output leading zeros for hex values < 0x10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printf("%x",hash[i]);` does not output a leading zero for hex values < 0x10.  You need to use `printf("%02x", hash[i]);` instead, which tells `printf()` to output a minimum of 2 hex digits, prepending a leading zero if needed.

Otherwise, use C++ stream output instead:

```
std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << (int)hash[i];
```

Which you also need to do for your `std::streamstream`, as your code for that is also omitting leading zeros for hex values < 0x10.

Comment: it's actually ```cpp std::setfill('0')``` and thanks !

Comment: @halius I fixed it

Answer (score 1):

You should be using something like:

```
printf("%02x",hash[i]);
```

to print out the bytes. This will correctly handle hex values less than 16 which, in your version, will simply output a *single* hex digit.

You can see that in the following program:

```
#include <cstdio>

#define FMT "%02x"
int main() {
    printf(FMT, 0x4b);
    printf(FMT, 0x05);
    printf(FMT, 0xc8);
    putchar('\n');
}
```

With `FMT` defined as above, you see the correct `4b05c8`. With it defined (as you have) as `"%x"`, you see the errant `4b5c8`.

---

And, just as an aside, you *may* want to consider ditching the C legacy stuff<sup>(a)</sup> like `printf`. I know it's in the standard but hardly anyone<sup>(b)</sup> uses it because of its limitations, despite the `iostream` equivalent being much more verbose.

Or do what we've done and just use the `fmt` library for much more succinct but still type-safe output, especially since it's currently being targeted toward C+20 (hence will almost certainly become part of the standard at some point).

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Nobody wants to be known as a C+ programmer, that strange breed who never quite embraced the full power of the language :-)

<sup>(b)</sup> Based on the sample of a moderate number of C++ developers I've worked with :-)

Comment: _"hardly anyone uses it because of its limitations"_ [citation needed]

Comment: Citation provided :-)

Comment: I sometimes see people prefer stdio over iostreams because "it's faster". They also tend to throw `std::endl` around like confetti when using iostreams, though, so...

Comment: TIL about leading zeros . I will start using fmt library I guess it's much better than the usual iostream for pretty printing.